# logical expressions in R, what makes is.na(x) return NA

Tags: r, ggplot2, logical-operators, tidyverse

I am doing the exercises in Hadley Wickham's ggplot2 book, and I am struggling with the question here, figuring out what ? represents:

Question- Fill in the question marks in this table:
[image]

There is no doubt that the first ? represents !x, since x is marked TRUE.
But, what makes is.na(x) NA? Also, I am kind of confused with the last two ?'s. If anyone could help me with these, it would be wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: Posting sample data in images is not recommended, kindly post it in text sample input and sample output and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It's a sample data, but the question simply asks to fill in the ? marks. x is just plain x, with no data input given in this question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, nor do I understand the problem. You say that *"x is marked TRUE"*. Is that so for all cases? What are the columns? Or are these the values for `x`? Then what is "Expression"? Can you provide a link to the original exercise in Hadley's book?

Comment: @Maurits Evers x in the Expression column is an object, and the x mark to the right side indicates the value or value of an operation. So the question is asking to fill in the ? marks, so it matches the x and x marks in this whole table. Hope this clarifies the question..

Comment: @commentallez-vous No sorry, I still don't understand; please provide a link to the relevant section in Hadley's book. In row 1, `x` returns `TRUE` because trivially `x <- TRUE`; ok. In row 2, you're looking for an expression that returns `FALSE` which as you say would be `!x`. So far so good. In row 3, the expression `is.na(x)` returns `FALSE` for `x <- TRUE` so why is this flagged as `NA`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Same here...I didn't understand this question either..It's the Hadley Wickham's "ggplot2 elegant graphics for data analysis" 2ed Chapter 10 Data Transformation Exercises 10.2.3's Question 2.

Comment: @commentallez-vous Does the book not give more information? I tried unsuccessfully to find a copy of the book, so I'm afraid I'm out. Sorry. Perhaps somebody will be able to clarify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174919/discussion-between-commentallez-vous-and-maurits-evers).

Answer (score 0):

After some confusion on my part (see comments), I interpret the question in the following way:

Given values for `x` indicated by crosses in columns `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `NA`, what expression returns a `TRUE` value?

Row 1: `x <- TRUE`; the expression `x` returns `TRUE`
Row 2: `x <- FALSE`; the expression `!x` returns `TRUE`
Row 3: `x <- NA`; the expression `is.na(x)` returns `TRUE`
Row 4: `x <- TRUE` or `x <- FALSE`; the expression `!is.na(x)` returns `TRUE`
Row 5: `x <- TRUE` or `x <- NA`; the expression `is.na(x) | x` returns `TRUE`
Row 6: `x <- FALSE` or `x <- NA`; the expression `is.na(x) | !x` returns `TRUE`